# IOS. Screened symbols in URL

Tags: ios, xcode, url, swift3

I need to send a request to a server and get a response.

I have the following URL:

http://192.168.200.10:9044/api/tables/?filter={"open_visible":true,"related":false}

For the query I'm using Alamofire. Here are some ways how I do it:

1)

```
class func getTables(completion: @escaping (_ response : DataResponse<TablesResponse>) -> Void) {
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    let getTablesPath = apiEntryPoint + "tables/?filter={\"open_visible\":true,\"related\":false}"

    Alamofire.request(getTablesPath)
        .validate()
        .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<TablesResponse>) in
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            completion(response)
    }
}
```

I get the error: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAEUh.png)

2)

```
class func getTables(completion: @escaping (_ response : DataResponse<TablesResponse>) -> Void) {
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    let getTablesPath = apiEntryPoint + "tables/?filter={%22open_visible%22:true,%22related%22:false}"

    Alamofire.request(getTablesPath)
        .validate()
        .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<TablesResponse>) in
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            completion(response)
    }
}
```

I get the error.

3)

```
class func getTables(completion: @escaping (_ response : DataResponse<TablesResponse>) -> Void) {
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    var getTablesPath = apiEntryPoint + "tables/?filter="

    let jsonParameters = ["open_visible":true, "related":false]
    if let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonParameters, options: []) {
        if let content = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8) {
            getTablesPath += content
        }
    }

    Alamofire.request(getTablesPath)
        .validate()
        .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<TablesResponse>) in
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            completion(response)
    }
}
```

I get the error.

4)

```
class func getTables(completion: @escaping (_ response : DataResponse<TablesResponse>) -> Void) {
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    let getTablesPath = apiEntryPoint + "tables/"

    Alamofire.request(getTablesPath, parameters: ["open_visible":true, "related":false])
        .validate()
        .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<TablesResponse>) in
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            completion(response)
    }
}
```

I got all tables. Without taking into account the desired parameters. It's bad.

**QUESTION**

As I can send a request for the server, considering the necessary parameters.

Comment: Screenshots of mistakes for point [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II7AH.png) and [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAEUh.png) .

Comment: `{` and `}` are not characters that you can pass in an URL. You need to check your API's documentation on what format does it expect arguments for `filter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
let urlParameters = yourParametersString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

because you can't just pass `{` and `}` characters in URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use request parameter for more user-friendly.
Put your all request data into NSDictionary and send it to the server.

```
let parameters: NSDictionary = [
    "YOUR_KEY": YOUR_VALUE,
]

// Both calls are equivalent
Alamofire.request(YOUR_SERVER_ULR, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
Alamofire.request(YOUR_SERVER_ULR, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding(options: []))
```

Another way is that, if you are passing some special character into your question parameter then you have encoded the URL.

```
let URL = YOUR_FINAL_URL_TO_SERVER.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

You can check out [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/WorkingwithURLEncoding/WorkingwithURLEncoding.html) for more detail.